# Array Reduce PHP

Tags: php

I have an     :

```
$arr = array(321,0.4,0.8,1.2);
$result = array_reduce($arr,create_function('$op1,$op2','return $op1-=$op2;'));
echo $result; //the result should be 318.6, but i got -323.4
```

would you please tell me what's wrong with this?

Comment: So how can i get the result=318.6?

thanks

Comment: You will get the result `318.6` with `$arr = array(321,0.4,0.8,1.2);
$result = array_reduce($arr,create_function('$op1,$op2','return $op1-=$op2;'), $arr[0]*2);
echo $result;`

Comment: $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$initial = array_shift($arr);
$result = array_reduce($arr, create_function('$op1,$op2','return $op1=-$op2;'),$initial);
echo $result;

Answer (score 6):

The array_reduce function has 3 parameters. The 3rd is $initial.

This is by default NULL. You should fill this one too. Look here: http://nl.php.net/array_reduce

> If the optional initial is available, it will be used at the
>   beginning of the process, or as a final result in case the array is
>   empty.

Comment: Why a down vote on this? This is the answer. On the first function call it will be `null -= 321` which will result to `-321`, then on the consequent calls it will be `-321 -= 0.4`, ...

Answer (score 2):

Just substract the sum of all elements but the first from the first element:

```
echo array_shift($arr) - array_sum($arr); # 318.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
array_reduce($arr,
       create_function('$op1,$op2','print "$op1, $op2\n"; 
                                    return $op1-=$op2;'));
```

and all should become clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `array_reduce` in the wrong way. The first item in the array needs to be shifted out of the array and used as the initial value.

```
$arr = array(321,0.4,0.8,1.2);
$initial = array_shift($arr);
$result = array_reduce($arr, create_function('$op1,$op2','return $op1-=$op2;'), $initial);
echo $result;
```

Comment: $arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
    $initial = array_shift($arr);
    $result = array_reduce($arr,   create_function('$op1,$op2','return $op1=-$op2;'),$initial);
   echo $result;

I need something like ((((1-2)-3)-4)-5)-6 = -19, but result above is not the same like what i need, please kindly help me.

Thanks

Comment: You have an error in your statement. $op1=-$op2 should be $op1-=$op2. The -= means "take left, substract right and save to left" while =- only means "save negative of right to left".