# calculate the arithmetic elements of php array?

Tags: php, arrays

this i my array

`$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);`

How to get the result that calculate the value of this expression `((((1-2) -3)-4)-5)`?

Comment: You mean like this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595255/array-reduce-php

Comment: You mean you want the integer result of that, or that literal string?

Comment: See the link @hakre posted in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 times the first entry minus the whole sum - looks pretty quick.

```
echo (2 * reset($arr)) - array_sum($arr);
```

Comment: Note: The use of reset to get the first element of the array is much better than using $arr[0] because it works with the following:  $arr = (-1 => 1, 0 => 2, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 5);  $arr = array();

Answer (score 3):

Just substract the sum of all elements but the first from the first element:

```
echo array_shift($arr) - array_sum($arr); # -13
```

To preserve the array, change the calculation a little:

```
echo $arr[0]*2 - array_sum($arr);  # -13
```

And we're glad you didn't ask for `eval`:

```
echo eval('return '.implode('-', $arr).';'); # -13
```

However the best suggestion I can give is that you encapsulate the logic into a class and overload the array with it. So that the object than can provide a method for the calculation ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WHUjOf)):

```
class Operands extends ArrayObject
{
    public function operate($sign)
    {
        $sign = max(-1, min(1, $sign.'1'));
        $arr = $this->getArrayCopy ();
        return $arr[0]*(1-$sign) + $sign*array_sum($arr);
    }
    public function __invoke($sign) {
        return $this->operate($sign);
    }
}

$arr = new Operands($arr);

echo $arr('-'), ', ' , $arr('+');
```

Comment: This changes the array, which may not be desired. Not that that's a good or bad thing, since @newbie never stated the array must remain intact.

Comment: Added some examples that don't do that and - if the calculation is needed multiple times - another example how to "overload" the array. Was not specified in the question either, but might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo eval(implode("-", $arr)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
// load the first number to subtract
$result = $arr[0];
$i = 1;
foreach($arr as $item)
{
    if ($i !=1) // skip the first one
        $result -= $item;
    $i++;
}
echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Following your example (1-2-3-4-5) should give -13. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
<?php
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
   $calc -= $val;
}

echo $calc;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @mOrSa, but more readable:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// load the first number to subtract
$result = $arr[0];

for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{        
    $result -= $arr[i];
}
echo $result;    
?>
```